# Linking to other page based on datalist option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

Now I have a datalist with a few options, and I want to link to other page when one of them is selected.
Below is my first attempt, in which I tried to directly add a hyper link to the option label. But it did not seem to work.

```
    <input type="text" name="my-input" list="my-list">
    <datalist id="my-list">
    <option value="a"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions"></a>a</option>
    <option value="b"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions"></a>b</option>
    <option value="c"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions"></a>c</option>
    </datalist>
```

Then I also tried to specify the onclick event of each option, and jump to other page accordingly, but still failed.
So is it possible to achieve this using datalist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[list='my-list']").on("input propertychange", function() {
    window.location = $("#my-list option[value='"+$("[list='my-list']").val()+"']").find("a").attr("href")
  });
});
```

[Here is the **CodePen** demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmjKWm)

Note that the page is blank after redirect because SO does not allow cross domain origin. Check your console to see the redirect attempt.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Your solution basically meets my requirement, but I expect the redirect to be triggered as soon as the option is selected; while in your provided solution, the page is not directed until the input is "focus out". So is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I changes the event binding for it to work and updated the code and Codepen demo link for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried your demo, which indeed solves the aforementioned problem. However, since the input event is used, the redirect now is triggered each time when the input value changes, while my initial idea is to redirect only when certain option is "clicked", which is why I tried using the click event.
Anyway, thanks to your solution, I now come up with a new approach, which is to check whether the input value matches the option, and fire the redirect only when they are matched.

Comment: @Shiying That is exactly what needs to be done if thats ur requirement. Filter the input, and check if it matches an item in a predefined list, and if it does, then redirect accordingly. Hope it helps u out :)

Comment: link not opening please check link of the codepen @Ahs N

Comment: @AhsN, If we type anything in the input field then also it's redirecting.