# href inside an <option> nested in a <datalist>

Tags: html, html-datalist

Is it possible to put an `<option>` with an `href` inside a `<datalist>`?

*For example:*

```
    <input type="image" src="SearchIconBlack.png" alt="Search Icon" onclick="SearchVisible()">
<form>
    <label>
        <input list="Websites" id="SearchBar" name="search" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </label>
    <datalist id="Websites">
        <option value="Home Page">Home</option>
        <option value="About Us">About Us</option>
    </datalist>
</form>
```

As you can see inside the option tag I want to add an `href` element. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you wish to have a dropdown with clickable links

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami No, I want a search for pages

Comment: @amn To have a proper search using <input> and find webpages using it

Comment: I am not sure how that will work. The `datalist` allows you to select pre-defined *text* stringsm, in your case for the `SearchBar` text input. That's well and good, no problem there. Now, what do you want to search for when they select one of the text strings from the datalist? You want to redirect the user to a certain location?

Comment: @amn Yes I want it to be a proper search area that redirects users to the appopriate link, like what Google does (if you get it)

Answer (score -2):

This could be achieved with the help of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("[list='Websites']").on("input propertychange", function() {
       window.location = $("#Websites option[value='"+$("[list='Websites']").val()+"']").find("a").attr("href")
   });
});
```

quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407919/5826265. Kindly see if this works.

Comment: An use case can never be non-sensical, Not like you have all the knowledge in the world. What if its like a course book index with a already expanded list which could take you to different course url. Any ways not worth my time arguing! Checkout the  SO post attached. Seems like many people are lost :P